# Type of pattern binder variable on RHS does not correspond to matched pattern on LHS

Tags: scala, casting, pattern-matching, instanceof, parameterized-types

Why does the partial function

```
val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v@Warped(Engineer(name: String)) => v.asInstanceOf[Warped[Engineer]]
}
```

seem to require `asInstanceOf` cast on RHS whilst the following does not

```
val engineers: PartialFunction[Crewmember, Engineer] = {
  case v@Engineer(name) => v
}
```

[given](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nnNB6UfnS7aKarE1njOlXw)

```
sealed trait Crewmember
case class Engineer(name: String) extends Crewmember
case class Commander(name: String) extends Crewmember

case class Warped[+A <: Crewmember](v: A)

val engineers: PartialFunction[Crewmember, Engineer] = {
  case v@Engineer(name) => v
}

val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v@Warped(Engineer(name: String)) => v.asInstanceOf[Warped[Engineer]]
}

val crew: List[Crewmember] = 
  List(Engineer("Geordi"), Commander("Picard"), Engineer("Scott"), Commander("Kirk"))

val warpedCrew: List[Warped[Crewmember]] = 
  List(Warped(Engineer("Geordi")), Warped(Commander("Picard")), Warped(Engineer("Scott")), Warped(Commander("Kirk")))

crew collect engineers
// res0: List[Engineer] = List(Engineer(Geordi), Engineer(Scott))

warpedCrew collect warpedEngineers
// res1: List[Warped[Engineer]] = List(Warped(Engineer(Geordi)), Warped(Engineer(Scott)))
```

Casting with `asInstanceOf` could be avoided like so

```
case Warped(eng: Engineer) => Warped(eng)
```

but I am wondering why does compiler not insert implicit `asInstanceOf` and instead types `v` to `Warped[Crewmember]`

```
val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v@Warped(Engineer(name: String)) => v 
}

Error: type mismatch;
 found   : Warped[Crewmember]
 required: Warped[Engineer]
      case v@Warped(Engineer(name: String)) => v
```

According to [SLS 8.1.3: Pattern Binders](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders)

> A pattern binder @ consists of a pattern variable  and a pattern
>   . The type of the variable  is the static type  implied by the
>   pattern . This pattern matches any value  matched by the pattern
>   , and it binds the variable name to that value.
>
> A pattern  implies a type  if the pattern matches only values of
>   the type .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Warped(Engineer(name))` on the left in

```
case v@Warped(Engineer(name: String)) => v
```

has static type `Warped[Crewmember]` because that's what you wrote in the type signature

```
val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], ...
```

So if you write just `v` on the right it's a type mismatch.

`Warped(Engineer(name))` on the right and on the left in

```
case Warped(Engineer(name)) => Warped(Engineer(name))
```

look similar but are different because they have different types. They are actually `Warped[Crewmember](Engineer(name))` and `Warped[Engineer](Engineer(name))`. Because of covariance `Warped[Engineer]` is a `Warped[Crewmember]` but not vice versa.

How is compiler supposed to guess that it should insert `asInstanceOf` here and shouldn't for example in `val x: Int = "a"`?

If you change the signature

```
val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Engineer], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v@Warped(Engineer(name)) => v
}
```

then static type of `v` will be `Warped[Engineer]` and the code will compile.

Similarly if you use typed pattern

```
val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v: Warped[Engineer] => v
}
```

then static type of `v` will be `Warped[Engineer]` and the code will compile.

It seems in terms of specification pattern `v@Warped(Engineer(name))` in

```
val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v@Warped(Engineer(name)) => ...
}
```

"implies" type `Warped[Crewmember]` (because of the signature).

Comment: Typed pattern `case v: Warped[Engineer] => v` does not work in say `collect` due to type erasure so it would not select just warped `Engineers`. Regarding _"How is compiler supposed to guess that it should insert asInstanceOf here and shouldn't for example in val x: Int = "a"?"_, doesn't pattern matching expand to combinations of `isInstanceOf/asInstanceOf` so it must be aware of at least `isInstanceOf[Wraped[_]` is true and `inInstanceOf[Engineer]` is true?

Comment: @MarioGalic ok let it be `val f: Any => Int = {
    case _ => "a"
  }`. Can you formulate the rule when additional `asInstanceOf` should be used?

Comment: @MarioGalic yeah, I know it doesn't work because of type erasure. I was talking about compilation, not whether it works at runtime.

Comment: @MarioGalic after your edit of the comment let it be `val f: Any => List[Int] = {
    case _ => List("a")
  }`.

Comment: @MarioGalic or even `val f: Any => List[Int] = { case _ => List[Any]("a") }`

Comment: @MarioGalic `val f: List[Any] => List[Int] = {
    case xs => xs
  }`

Comment: Just because a `v: Warped[T]` has an `Engineer` inside does not mean `T = Engineer`. `v = Warped[CrewMember](Engineer("Isaac"))` would satisfy the pattern (`v.isInstanceOf[Warped[_]] && v.v.isInstanceOf[Engineer]`) and yet would not be a `Warped[Engineer]`. Think about what would go wrong if `case class Warped[+T <: Crewmember](v: T) { val oops: T }`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Compiler seems to insert `asInstanceOf` in the following `val engineers: PartialFunction[Crewmember, Engineer] = { case v@Engineer(name) => v }` so here type of `v` is not determined by signature. How is `case _` relevant to constructor pattern or typed pattern?

Comment: @MarioGalic I can guess that the difference is whether pattern is monomorphic or polymorphic. For `v@Engineer(name)` the type is `Engineer`, for `v@Warped(Engineer(name))` the type is `Warped[T]` (`T >: Engineer`) and `T` was taken from the signature. See comments here https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/PatternTypers.scala#L208-L234 *How is `case _` relevant to constructor pattern or typed pattern?* I tried to show example which is similar to `Engineer`/`Warped` and should clearly be rejected. I guess it's not so easy to formulate the precise...

Comment: ... rule why `val f: List[Any] => List[Int] = { case xs => xs }` should be rejected and `val warpedEngineers: PartialFunction[Warped[Crewmember], Warped[Engineer]] = {
  case v@Warped(Engineer(name)) => v
}` should be accepted. There are always programs that work at runtime correctly but are rejected at compile time (`val x: Int = if (true) 1 else "a"`).